# How in APT to choose a specific source to provide installation instructions for virtual package?

Tags: 18.04, apt, php, php7

I'm trying to install PHP extension *php-ctype*. When I do

```
apt-get install php-ctype
```

it returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php-ctype is a virtual package provided by:
  php7.4-common 7.4.2-6+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php7.3-common 7.3.14-6+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php7.2-common 7.2.27-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
  php7.1-common 7.1.33-9+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php7.0-common 7.0.33-20+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php5.6-common 5.6.40-21+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
You should explicitly select one to install.
```

How do I choose one? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and PHP 7.2

Answer (score 1):

You should change the prefix:

```
apt-get install php7.2-ctype
```